# WiFi ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and my issue is that when I go on the WiFi button on my laptop, it shows that it is connected, but when I open the net it displays "no internet connection"

Can some one help me please

Comment: You are not giving us much to go on the connected icon is telling you that you that it is connected to a network but not necessarily that that network is connected to the internet.  Open a terminal and enter the command "ifconfig" without the quotes and edit your question to include the answer may help us figure out where to look next,

Answer (score 0):

The bubble that shows connected only depicts that there is a connection established between your wifi router the your laptop.

This doesn't still guarantee that you are reachable to internet. For that part you need to configure your wifi router.